# How to identify & choose unique properties for objects identification in QTP/UFT?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, vbscript

When I write test script (Descriptive programming) in QTP/UFT, I find difficult to figure out & choose unique properties for objects identification, now here I want to know that is there any way to figure out the best unique property for the same kind of objects.

Comment: You should add an example if possible of an object with his properties.

Comment: I am asking in a general way most of the time I manage but it takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there is not a single property which will uniquely identify the object and we have to use a number of properties to identify the one we are looking for. In my experience, you keep adding properties/attributes in your descriptive code until you find the object. I always start with "html id"or  "name" if there is one available as most of the times that is unique. If it is not I would always ask the developers if there are any specific reasons to do. Sometimes it takes them just a few seconds to add such unique property so it is always better to ask them! To achieve uniqueness, I have used combination of "micclass", "innertext", "html tag", "visible" and "title" properties but there may be more you can use depending on your project.

I hope it is helpful.